# Is there any hot reload for blazor server-side?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I have just one, quick question.
Is there way to hot reload a blazor app? At least, .razor files?
Now I'm hosting my app on local IIS (not IIS express).

I was looking through internet, but i didn't found anything helpful.

Thank you all for anwsering :)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Maybe you can try running your application from command prompt:

```
dotnet watch run debug
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working as it should be. Have a great day!

Comment: I actually had to use this in combination with :
    <script>
        Blazor.defaultReconnectionHandler._reconnectCallback = function (d) {
            document.location.reload();
        }
    </script>

Comment: Yay, this works beautifully. It makes the page reload automatically whenever there's a change - not totally seamless but almost there.

Comment: this works but there should be a better solution with simply pressing F5

Answer (score 23):

**Update 2021-11-10:**

With Visual Studio 2022 being released 2021-11-08 hot reload now works out of the box. Upgrade your project to `.NET 6` to get the best experience.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#NET-HotReload-170

**Update 2021-04-09:**

Initial .NET Hot Reload support for `.NET 6 Preview 3`

Add the "hotReloadProfile": "aspnetcore" property to your launch profile in launchSettings.json. For Blazor WebAssembly projects, use the "blazorwasm" hot reload profile.

Run the project using `dotnet watch`.

You can find a list of supported code edits in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/supported-code-changes-csharp?view=vs-2019).

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-3/#initial-net-hot-reload-support

Thanks @Quango for pointing it out.

**Update 2020-04-09:**

Instead of using `browser-sync` I have added the following code in `_Host.cshtml` under `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>`

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script>
        window.Blazor.defaultReconnectionHandler.onConnectionDown = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                location.reload();
            }, 7000);
        }
    </script>
</environment>
```

Not optimal but it works better since you need one less http server. Could also use `_reconnectCallback` if you still like to see the messages `Attempting to reconnect to the server...` and `Could not reconnect to the server. Reload the page to restore functionality.`.

```
window.Blazor.defaultReconnectionHandler._reconnectCallback = function (d) {
    document.location.reload();
}
```

https://thijstijsma.nl/2020/02/18/blazor-server-hot-reload/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59807998/3850405

**Original:**

Hot reloading is planned for .NET 5, which is scheduled for Nov 2020 according to @danroth27 who is working on the Blazor project.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5456#issuecomment-584219488

As @MauricioAtanache says you can use dotnet watch but don't forget to add which files to watch. Example:

```
dotnet watch --project BlazorTest.Server run
```

BlazorTest.Server.csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Watch Include="..\**\*.razor" />
    <Watch Include="..\**\*.scss" />
    <Watch Include="..\**\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

It is however not *true* hot reloading since it will restart the server but you have to do a manual refresh in the browser. You will also need to edit an existing file before a reload takes place if you add a new file.

To solve this I like to use `browser-sync` set up as a proxy to your web app.

Example:

```
browser-sync start --proxy https://localhost:5001/ --files '**/*.razor,**/*.cshtml, **/*.css, **/*.js, **/*.htm*'
```

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/May/18/Live-Reloading-Server-Side-ASPNET-Core-Apps

There is also a project on Github by @martasp called `BlazorLiveReload` that is supposed to handle Blazor Live Reload without refreshing page.

From author:

> It uses razor engine version 3 to compile components to c# classes.
> Then using Roslyn compiler I compiled down those classes to assembly.
> Finally, I loaded the app.razor component from an assembly with
> reflection and with Steve Sanderson Test host modified library I
> turned component to plain HTML. To serve HTML files in realtime I used
> WebSockets to have a full-duplex communication.

I have not tested this project myself so I can't say how well it works.

https://github.com/martasp/BlazorLiveReload

General thread about the issue:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5456

Comment: Looks like the hot reload functionality will not be shipped with .NET 5: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5456#issuecomment-666728638

Comment: Hot reload didn't work with these methods for me. A few tweaks has it working though. From Powershell run 2 windows: 1. `dotnet watch run`, 2. `browser-sync start --proxy https://localhost:5001/ --files 'bin/Debug/netstandard2.1/BlazorApp.dll'`. Without this, the browser-sync triggers too early and misses the changes

Comment: @axon This is excellent - it works, thanks!

Comment: Further update: [.NET 6.0 Preview 3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-3/) now enables hot reload proper

Comment: How to debug a client side using hot reloads?

Answer (score 7):

Thijs Tijsma had a [post](https://thijstijsma.nl/2020/02/18/blazor-server-hot-reload/) that worked for me.

You have to run without the debugger attached in `Visual Studio` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> in Visual Studio)

in the `Pages\_host.cshtml` add

```html
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

<!-- Make sure you place it after the include for blazor.server.js -->

<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/Scripts/HotReload.js"></script>
</environment>
```

Then just make the reload `js` file
`wwwroot\scripts\HotReload.js`

```js
window.Blazor.defaultReconnectionHandler.onConnectionDown = function ()
{
    window.location.reload();
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Just launch the project using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> (without attaching a debugger), make changes and reloads the page.

Answer (score 3):

### A history of pain

Currently there is no *real good* solution yet that re-compiles changed parts automatically and save as much time as possible, like *edit and continue*. Another sad fact is that [there is an open issue about it](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5456) since 2018 (!). They promise to finally fix this with .NET 6. We'll see if this is worth more, cause after pressure of the community, they [already promised a solution in the beginning of 2020 for .NET 5](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5456#issuecomment-584219488). About 6 months later, they had to tell that [they couldn't make it to release after all for v5.](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5456#issuecomment-666644982)

### Workaround *with* debugging

#### What doesn't worked

Running `dotnet watch run` is a good thing, but reaches its limitations when you want o use a debugger. Even with `dotnet watch run debug`, I couldn't make it work to attach Visual Studio to the process, so that it reachs breakpoints. I also tried to let VS run `dotnet watch run debug` with the following profile entry in `launchSettings.json`:

```
"WatchDebug": {
  "commandName": "Executable",
  "executablePath": "dotnet.exe",
  "commandLineArgs": "watch run debug",
  "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)",
  "launchBrowser": false,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

The process is started and got restarted when files were changed, but no breakpoint is hit. Also not with `dotnet run -c debug`.

[Then I found a setting in VS which looks good](https://github.com/dotnet/blazor/pull/193#issuecomment-755688296), but no effect, even not when using IIS Express:

[image]

#### The only workaround I found with debugging

Inject your config in `_Host.cshtml`

```
@inject IWebHostEnvironment env
```

and add the following call after `blazor.server.js`

```
@if (env.EnvironmentName != "Production") {
    <script>
        window.Blazor.defaultReconnectionHandler.onConnectionDown = function () {
            console.log('reloading')
            window.location.reload();
        };
    </script>
}
```

Now create a debug configuration in `launchSettings.json` *without* launching the browser, cause this would let you click the page you want to test on *every* change, which we'd like to avoid:

```
"MyProjectWithoutBrowser": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

Make sure the env variable got only set to `Debug` during development and `Production` otherwise. Open the browser on the given Url. If you choose that config and changes were applied, press `[Ctrl] + [Shift] + [F5]`. This would restart the debugger, then the browser re-connects and you see the changes. On a hello world Blazor Server app, this takes about ~3-4 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

There is now support for stateful Blazor hot-reload in LiveSharp (https://www.livesharp.net)

You can see it working here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCh5-44UBpM

LiveSharp is a commercial tool that allows you to update C# code in runtime.

Disclaimer: I'm the author

Comment: Should mention that it is a monthly fee between €9.90 and €19 depending on personal / business use.

Comment: it's now free (and open source)

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Watch Include="..\**\*.razor" />
    <Watch Include="..\**\*.scss" />
    <Watch Include="..\**\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to your .csproj and then run:

```
dotnet watch run debug
```

This is not a hot reload as you might expect but it automates the re-run process. You'll just have to wait some seconds and reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

With dotnet 6.0

In the **Tasks.json** add a new part like below and call it for example **watchRunBuild**

(It is copy of **build** but I had added **watch** and **Run** to the parameters of **args** like this :

```
  {
        "label": "watchRunBuild",
        "command": "dotnet",
        "type": "process",
        "args": [
            "watch",
            "run",
            "build",
            "${workspaceFolder}/BlazorTest.csproj",
            "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
            "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
```

And in the **launch.json**

Change **preLaunchTask** to **watchRunBuild** like this :

```
 "preLaunchTask": "watchRunBuild"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where VS would tell me "This error was not expected. your debugging process might be corrupted and restarting it is recommended".

I was using responsecompression on the server. Disabling it in Development fixed my issue.

Example of my solution:

```
builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.EnableForHttps = true;
    options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
});

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();

}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseResponseCompression();
}
```