# Visual Studio Blazor WYSIWYG Designer

Tags: visual-studio, blazor

Is there a way in Visual Studio to easily edit blazor web pages ?
For now, I code everything by hand !

It is very time consuming ! For each change I have to rebuild, restart, etc...
I've spent 3 days to create a nice web page, instead of hours !

Any idea ? How do you do ?

Thanks

Comment: There is no WYSIWYG for Blazor that I'm aware of, but you dont need to stop rebuild and start the project again. Try running dotnet watch run and then starting with Ctrl F5, which you will lose debugging but when you make changes you wont have to restart the project. When designing it makes for a much faster development experience. 

There is work to make this a better process which you can follow here:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5456

Answer (score 8):

There is a free version of [Radzen.com](https://Radzen.com)

Comment: As for 2023 they created a new tool even better than the original. Radzen Blazor Studio. I use it for initial scafolding of my razor pages and then I continue editing code in Visual Studio. https://www.radzen.com/blazor-studio/

Answer (score 0):

No designer is available for blazor, and to my knowledge this is also not planned.

To speedup your development workflow you could use hot reloading. Check this: [Is there any hot reload for blazor server-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58172922/is-there-any-hot-reload-for-blazor-server-side)