# Auto reconnect Blazor Serverside

Tags: .net-core, blazor

Blazor serverside (dotnet core 3.1)

I run into the problem that on customer side this is shown:

> Could not reconnect to the server. Reload the page to restore functionality.

Each time I update the code base or internet is broken or something like this.

Now the goal is that it should reload the page as soon as the server is back again (or in some interval).

Is there any possibility that could help me?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

<script>
   Blazor.defaultReconnectionHandler._reconnectCallback = function(d) {
        document.location.reload(); 
   }
</script>
```

Comment: When application depends on the build time. Can breaks by browser timeout. But can work for deployment to site.

Comment: @Softlion I tested this solution and it is working. I added the override of the reconnectCallback to my _Host.cshtml

Comment: I gor a error:Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_reconnectCallback')

Comment: No longer a solution in .Net 6 as the `_reconnectCallback` has been removed.

Comment: Check the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60031891/7606096. Tested and it works.

Comment: @aryeh do you know if this has been replaced by something else?

Comment: @d0rf47 yes I wrote a post about it: https://alldev.co.uk/reload-blazor-server-on-connection-down-in-net-6/

Comment: Added it as a solution below

Answer (score 25):

```js
<script>
    // Wait until a 'reload' button appears
    new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
        if (document.querySelector('#components-reconnect-modal h5 a')) {
            // Now every 10 seconds, see if the server appears to be back, and if so, reload
            async function attemptReload() {
                await fetch(''); // Check the server really is back
                location.reload();
            }
            observer.disconnect();
            attemptReload();
            setInterval(attemptReload, 10000);
        }
    }).observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
</script>
```

This will wait until the reload button appears and then will wait until the server is back  up before actually reloading.

From https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10325#issuecomment-537979717

Comment: My server is behind a proxy server, so this would cause the reload to show the proxy error page. I added "if (response.ok)" just before the location.reload() and that fixes it - the proxy reports an error, and the code keeps retrying because it wasn't a 2xx response.

Comment: That solution is working correct for me.
You can also hide the reload if you change the querySelector to only '#components-reconnect-modal' and make a custom css for the #components-reconnect-modal with display: none !important;
In that way the reload is nearly imperceptible to the user.

Answer (score 14):

For .NET 6 & 7 you can use:

```js
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
<script>
    Blazor.start().then(() => {
        Blazor.defaultReconnectionHandler._reconnectCallback = function (d) {
            document.location.reload();
        }
    });
</script>
```

This keeps all of the original startup process as is and just adds a page reload on connection down, without needing a mutations observer.

Comment: Cheers thank you for adding this! Checking the article out now too

Answer (score 4):

For .Net 8 ([Base on SignalIR documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-8.0))

App.Razor:

```
<div id="reconnect-modal" style="display: none;"></div>
<script src="{BLAZOR SCRIPT}" autostart="false"></script>
<script src="boot.js"></script>
```

For example, if you have a Blazor Web app

```html
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode=RenderMode.InteractiveServer />
    <div id="reconnect-modal" style="display: none;"></div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js" autostart="false"></script>
    <script src="boot.js"></script>
</body>
```

Create boot.js on wwwroot (wwwroot/boot.js)

One way to determine the type of your Blazor project is to check the script tag that references the Blazor framework. If your project is a Blazor Web App, you will see a script tag with the src attribute set to _framework/blazor.web.js. This indicates that your Blazor app runs on the browser and uses WebAssembly to execute the .NET code.

boot.js content for a Blazor Web App:

```js
(() => {
  const maximumRetryCount = 3;
  const retryIntervalMilliseconds = 5000;
  const reconnectModal = document.getElementById('reconnect-modal');

  const startReconnectionProcess = () => {
    reconnectModal.style.display = 'block';

    let isCanceled = false;

    (async () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < maximumRetryCount; i++) {
        reconnectModal.innerText = `Attempting to reconnect: ${i + 1} of ${maximumRetryCount}`;

        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, retryIntervalMilliseconds));

        if (isCanceled) {
          return;
        }

        try {
          const result = await Blazor.reconnect();
          if (!result) {
            // The server was reached, but the connection was rejected; reload the page.
            location.reload();
            return;
          }

          // Successfully reconnected to the server.
          return;
        } catch {
          // Didn't reach the server; try again.
        }
      }

      // Retried too many times; reload the page.
      location.reload();
    })();

    return {
      cancel: () => {
        isCanceled = true;
        reconnectModal.style.display = 'none';
      },
    };
  };

  let currentReconnectionProcess = null;

  Blazor.start({
    circuit: {
      reconnectionHandler: {
        onConnectionDown: () => currentReconnectionProcess ??= startReconnectionProcess(),
        onConnectionUp: () => {
          currentReconnectionProcess?.cancel();
          currentReconnectionProcess = null;
        }
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

boot.js content for a Blazor Server

```js
(() => {
  const maximumRetryCount = 3;
  const retryIntervalMilliseconds = 5000;
  const reconnectModal = document.getElementById('reconnect-modal');

  const startReconnectionProcess = () => {
    reconnectModal.style.display = 'block';

    let isCanceled = false;

    (async () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < maximumRetryCount; i++) {
        reconnectModal.innerText = `Attempting to reconnect: ${i + 1} of ${maximumRetryCount}`;

        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, retryIntervalMilliseconds));

        if (isCanceled) {
          return;
        }

        try {
          const result = await Blazor.reconnect();
          if (!result) {
            // The server was reached, but the connection was rejected; reload the page.
            location.reload();
            return;
          }

          // Successfully reconnected to the server.
          return;
        } catch {
          // Didn't reach the server; try again.
        }
      }

      // Retried too many times; reload the page.
      location.reload();
    })();

    return {
      cancel: () => {
        isCanceled = true;
        reconnectModal.style.display = 'none';
      },
    };
  };

  let currentReconnectionProcess = null;

  Blazor.start({
    reconnectionHandler: {
      onConnectionDown: () => currentReconnectionProcess ??= startReconnectionProcess(),
      onConnectionUp: () => {
        currentReconnectionProcess?.cancel();
        currentReconnectionProcess = null;
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

Create App.razor.css on Components folder (same folder of App.razor)

```
#reconnect-modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 100; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7); /* White w/ opacity */

    color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    padding-top: 27px; 
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This also leads to a 404 when internet is disconnected even when the user has not interacted with the web page: that is not expected. So I replaced the for/retrycount loop by a while(true) and disabled the  location.reload(); on "Retried too many times; reload the page".

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative but I'm not sure it works 100%.

```
<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>

<script>
    Blazor.start().then(() => {
        Blazor.defaultReconnectionHandler._reconnectionDisplay = {
            show: () => {},
            update: (d) => {},
            rejected: (d) => document.location.reload()
        };
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys am sure still many are facing the problem(Could not reconnect to the server. Reload the page to restore functionality.) even on .Net 8 & none of above mentioned solution working. So only solutions is stay plain. So just remove all these extra flavours & use default its better than any other these stuffs. Even am with boot.js from last 1-2 year now thats also not working. So stay simple , through that whenever reopen the tab its austastart=true makes call & restarts the connect...

@* by default  autostart is true*@  @Microsoft

Answer (score -2):

One trick some people forget about is that you can actually "watch" your code base for changes, if you open your favorite terminal and run `dotnet run watch debug` in the same folder as your cproj file it should watch your changes so when you refresh your browser it should pick up any changes to your application, formore information read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-3.1

> dotnet watch is a tool that runs a .NET Core CLI command when source files change. For example, a file change can trigger compilation, test execution, or deployment.

Hope this helps

Comment: It doesn't appear to have any effect on whether or not the browser reloads.