# How to deploy Blazor server in production and overcome SignalR re-connection problems?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Blazor server is a fantastic technology, but it constantly breaks with SignalR not being able to reconnect to the server.

How would one fix this in production? I'm having people leaving their laptops in sleep or putting phone with website for a 5 seconds away, than - "Attempting to reconnect".

And always failed. Users are waiting just to see "Reload" button.

Hot to overcome this issue and force reconnect SignalR, even if website was not active in mobile browsers or browsers of sleeping pc?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use Blazor Webassembly. It is production ready since May 2020, Version 3.2.0, .NET Core 3.1

Comment: Blazor WebAssembly is great but isn't fit for all possible use cases.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Overview

Blazor has built in options for [customising the startup process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0#modify-the-reconnection-handler-blazor-server)

and to [Configure the SignalR client for Blazor Server apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0#circuit-handler-options-for-blazor-server-apps)

They have even added a [sample for how to automatically reload when reconnecting fails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0#automatically-refresh-the-page-when-reconnection-fails-blazor-server).

### Sample - taken from the docs at this date:

##### First, turn off the Blazor boot process with `autostart="false"` and register your `boot.js` script

```html
<body>
    ...

    <div id="reconnect-modal" style="display: none;"></div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
    <script src="boot.js"></script>
</body>
```

##### Then, you can provide your own connection handler and settings in boot.js

```javascript
(() => {
  const maximumRetryCount = 3;
  const retryIntervalMilliseconds = 5000;
  const reconnectModal = document.getElementById('reconnect-modal');

  const startReconnectionProcess = () => {
    reconnectModal.style.display = 'block';

    let isCanceled = false;

    (async () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < maximumRetryCount; i++) {
        reconnectModal.innerText = `Attempting to reconnect: ${i + 1} of ${maximumRetryCount}`;

        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, retryIntervalMilliseconds));

        if (isCanceled) {
          return;
        }

        try {
          const result = await Blazor.reconnect();
          if (!result) {
            // The server was reached, but the connection was rejected; reload the page.
            location.reload();
            return;
          }

          // Successfully reconnected to the server.
          return;
        } catch {
          // Didn't reach the server; try again.
        }
      }

      // Retried too many times; reload the page.
      location.reload();
    })();

    return {
      cancel: () => {
        isCanceled = true;
        reconnectModal.style.display = 'none';
      },
    };
  };

  let currentReconnectionProcess = null;

  Blazor.start({
    reconnectionHandler: {
      onConnectionDown: () => currentReconnectionProcess ??= startReconnectionProcess(),
      onConnectionUp: () => {
        currentReconnectionProcess?.cancel();
        currentReconnectionProcess = null;
      },
    },
  });
})();
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for good answer with an example! It will help a lot! While I'm trying to implement my own reconnection, I'm wondering, didn't blazor team write their own reconnection code which for some reason breaks? I mean I suspect they have something like you wrote, with reconnection and page reload. But for some reason their code always happens to fail to reconnect. No internet for 1-2 seconds, and blazor server side js is dead, not connecting. It's like it doesn't recognize server or something, forgets about it. I will try to write and debug my own though

Comment: There is reconnection code but it doesn't do an automatic reload. There are also settings on the server side about how long a circuit can be disconnected before it is disposed.

Comment: do you by chance know where in blazor server this can be configured? Somewhere in Startup.cs?

Comment: Yes, I think the best link is this as it explains the security implications of any changes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/server?view=aspnetcore-3.1#denial-of-service-dos-attacks

Comment: It would be really nice if you could add best practice for this use case, since this is obviously not suitable for production.

Comment: @PhilippMichalski Microsoft have now updated the documentation - so I have replaced my sample with theirs and provided links to the docs - I would consider this to be "suitable for production" if you take the time to understand the code and validate it is the correct behaviour for your application.

Comment: When I tried to implement this solution I got the error message: System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.ClientProxyExtensions.SendAsync(IClientProxy clientProxy, String method, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR\ClientProxyExtensions.cs:line 26

Comment: What I don't understand is how I am supposed to keep the "autostart=false" part from breaking absolutely everything else 

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question and my answer may be irrelevant, but it may help too!

I had the same problem with Blazor in production: Continuously (every 1 minute) getting the reconnect error, but everything else (Blazor functionalities) had worked well. I am using Apache Linux to host my Blazor app. I figured out that the web socket connection was failing with a 502 error, and Blazor tried to reconnect it, but it would fall again. Finally, I understood that the problem is the bad configuration for Apache. I changed the conf from

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
</VirtualHost>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass / ws://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / ws://127.0.0.1:5000/
</VirtualHost>
```

and it completely solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler solution than Mister Magoo, you could use:

```html
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
  <script>
    Blazor.start().then(() => {
      Blazor.defaultReconnectionHandler._reconnectCallback = function (d) {
        document.location.reload();
      }
    });
</script>
```

This keeps the original startup process and just adds a reload when connection goes down.

Comment: This is more of a work around than a solution. It forces a reload/refresh of the page and can impact user experience by reseting javascript state. The author and myself are looking for a solution where the client would reconnect to the server without having to reload the entire page.

Comment: Correct. I would also prefer a reconnect but that is currently not possible. This issue is being tracked here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30344 and hopefully .NET 8 will provide this.

Comment: When I implement this solution I get the message: System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.ClientProxyExtensions.SendAsync(IClientProxy clientProxy, String method, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR\ClientProxyExtensions.cs:line 26