# Blazor Connection Disconnected

Tags: .net-core, signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a web app with Client running on Blazor Server. I have set a custom Blazor reconnect modal (`<div id="components-reconnect-modal"...`) as the documentation says here - [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&pivots=server)

Also I have these settings for SignalR and Blazor circuits:

```
    services.AddServerSideBlazor
        (options =>
        {
            options.DisconnectedCircuitMaxRetained = 100;
            options.DisconnectedCircuitRetentionPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.JSInteropDefaultCallTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            options.MaxBufferedUnacknowledgedRenderBatches = 10;
        })
        .AddHubOptions(options =>
        {
            options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            options.EnableDetailedErrors = false;
            options.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
            options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
            options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 32 * 1024;
            options.StreamBufferCapacity = 10;
        });
```

But I have an annoying problem - Whenever the app is open in a browser tab and stays still with nobody using it it disconnects. It happens very inconsistently and I can't locate the configuration for these custom time periods but I need to enlarge them. Example:

1. Initialy loaded the app at 11:34:24AM
2. Leave it like that for a while
3. In the Console: "Information: Connection disconnected." at 11:55:48AM and my reconnect-modal appears.

How can I enlarge the lifetime of the connection so that it is always bigger than my session timeout. I checked the Private Memory Limit of my app pool but it is unlimited. It happens really inconsistently with the same steps to reproduce. Test 1 - 16 mins 20 sec; Test 2 - 21 mins 58 sec; Test 3 - 34 mins 56 sec...and then after iisreset...Test 4 - 6 mins 28 sec

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is by design. Once the client is idle for some time it essentially stops sending pings to the server. Then the server only knows tha the client has disconnected and drops the details to allow for resource reuse. You can edit the times and count of “inactive” connections as you have done in the CircuitOptions, but at some point if the client is idle it will disconnect.

have a look at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-3.1&pivots=server

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can go around this error by using this code in _Host.cshtml:

```
<script>
    Blazor.start().then(() => {
        Blazor.defaultReconnectionHandler._reconnectionDisplay = {
            show: () => {},
            update: (d) => {},
            rejected: (d) => document.location.reload()
        };
    });
</script>
```

Please read also about [`Modify the reconnection handler (Blazor Server)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0#reflect-the-connection-state-in-the-ui-blazor-server)

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031791/how-to-deploy-blazor-server-in-production-and-overcome-signalr-re-connection-pro/60031891#60031891)

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosting on IIS?
Is the default IIS App Pool recycling set to 20 mins of Idle?
You could try and set this to 0.