# How to tell, whether connection has been lost due to network connectivity or unhandled exception

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to handle cases, when user is occasionally offline and the server session is disposed.

Currently I get the same UX as when there is unhandled exception thrown.

[image]

How do I differentiate between expired session and unhandled exception

Comment: Well, once the circuit is interrupted and you see that error banner, your user is in an unrecoverable state.  So I'm curious what you would do even if you could distinguish this scenario.

Comment: Simply reload :) My app state is persistent, so reload is exactly what user would do anyway. Reason for disconnect is that the user simply turns off his device temporarily and later reopens

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  There's another question/answer that is related that you may find useful if you haven't seen it already:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031791/how-to-deploy-blazor-server-in-production-and-overcome-signalr-re-connection-pro/60031891#60031891