# Blazor Server client side with SignalR doesn't work

Tags: blazor, signalr, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

We have a problem with a Blazor server application. Our application shows real time data all day. If we run that for few hours, we haven't a problem, but during a long run test, after 10 hours or more, the client side stops to work (sometimes no switch between pages, sometimes stop refresh data with SignalR).

If we close and reopen the browser page, the application starts to work again. There isn't any error in our logs and in the Windows [Event Viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer).

We have the same behavior in Visual Studio 2022 debug mode and in [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) after application publish.
How can I fix this problem?

1. Reduced memory usage in the client side.
2. Implemented OnDisconnect with SignalR for delete inactive connections.
3. Set IIS idle-time out to 0 for never close connections with clients

Comment: Be sure to dispose your hubs connections when needed, be sure also to don't initialize a lot of hubs instances for some reasons.  And be sure to publish in release mode.

Comment: We tried to publish in debug and release mode, each blazor page have Dispose method with hubconnection.StopAsync(), is better use disposeAsync()?
We have only one hub for all hubs connection and in each page we created a             hubConnection object

Comment: My advise is to call `DisposeAsync` if hub isn't needed anymore.

Comment: We will try and tomorrow will update you

Comment: @E.Benedos thanks for your advise, should be  right way

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas to further troubleshoot.  The issue is that the SignalR connection between the browser and Blazor Server is becoming disconnected.  When this happens, the browser will not receive updates to the page DOM and you experience "no switch between pages".  If you are debugging Blazor Server locally, you can reproduce a SignalR disconnection by waiting at a debug breakpoint.

1. Inspect browser DevTools when this error happens.  If the browser loses the SignalR connection, there should be an exception in the JS Console.  This will confirm the SignalR disconnection and possibly provide a hint of the root cause (ie, possible unhandled app exception in your .razor code)
2. Consider establishing the SignalR connection manually using JS.  This [SO thread/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031791/how-to-deploy-blazor-server-in-production-and-overcome-signalr-re-connection-pro) has some info on how to set this up for Blazor Server using JS code.  This approach gives you a chance to detect the disconnection (from the browser/client) and automatically reconnect from the browser.
3. [Consider using a hosted Azure SignalR Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0#azure-signalr-service-blazor-server) for better connectivity.  Note that you can configure the Circuit and Hub timeout options if those are the root cause.
4. Implement a [CircuitHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.server.circuits.circuithandler?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to track the SignalR connections on your Blazor Server.  This will help monitor the SignalR connections from the server.    You can use this to identify when you lose connections on the server side and possibly trigger a page refresh to reconnect.

Lastly, consider that the SignalR connection may be broken between the browser and your Blazor Server.  For example, some users can't access a Blazor Server app over VPN connections, because the SignalR/WebSocket connection is broken.  It's possible that IIS has some timeout that is affecting your app.

Comment: Thanks, we will implements a  CircuitHandler for a better connections tracking

Answer (score 0):

There is no code attached (it would help if there was callback registation shown), so I can only guess. When you call `hubConnection.On`, notice that it returns `IDisposable`. It's used to get rid of the suscription when it's no longer needed. As far as I can tell (after brief look at the code), SignalR doesn't keep reference to the subscription object. If your component doesn't hold it either, GC will collect it after some time, canceling your subscription. And of course there would be no errors in any log in such case.

Sad thing is, the example chat app in MS documentation doesn't hold to the subscription objects either...

Hope it helps, described symptoms match what I would expect from my app too, if it stayed on one page long enough (I was just trying to understand blazor-server SignalR when I noticed this potential problem and was searching for more information).