# LiveReload for Blazor Server Side app in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, blazor, livereload

Is it possible to enable live reload for Blazor Server Side app in Visual Studio?

By default, not only it does not reload, but does it not recompiles either.
After I change a razor file and save in visual studio, refresh in browser does nothing

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58172922/is-there-any-hot-reload-for-blazor-server-side

Comment: It's not duplicate, because the command line does not start Visual Studio debugging session

Comment: @Liero you asked for live reload, the referenced question does what you want. If you want debugging and reload you're kind of asking about Edit-and-Continue, which isn't supported

Comment: Isn't edit then continue what we mean by Live Reload? As with Xamarin.

Comment: OK due in Nov with .NET 5.

Comment: @Quango: Edit and Continue is not live reload, because you have to actually hit breakpoint to do any changes. besides it does not work with async stuff in blazor.

Answer (score 0):

As of .NET 6.0 Preview 3 there is now a Hot Reload capability.

Blog article introducing this at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-3/

Comment: Or https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-hot-reload/.