# Is it possible to enable changes to .cshtml in debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, blazor, .net-5

Running the template blazor .Net 5 application in vS21019, I notice that any changes I do in the .cshtml files are not shown while running the application in debug (refresh has no effect).

Probably because razor content is not re-compiled during execution.

Added the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation Nuget package, as I thought it might help, but it has no effect.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio.

Is this possible? I'm used to do runtime design changes, so I really miss not having the option here.

[image]

Comment: Yes. It does not give me the answer I would like, but it does answer my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best you can do in Blazor right now is to run from the console with

```
dotnet watch run debug
```

There is no [real hot reload in blazor](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5456#issuecomment-584219488) yet, and that package you found is for MVC, not Blazor.

> Make sure to add project settings to tell the watcher what to watch so it does not watch everything. While trying to find resources on this I came upon this thread that adds tons more information and a few more ideas [Better StackOverflow thread on hot reloading in blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58172922/is-there-any-hot-reload-for-blazor-server-side)

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of another VS setting that does about the same - I keep it to None usually because I want control on when things build, but you can try playing with it

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Not quite was I was hoping for. I hope they'll add it soon. I am so used to hot reloading, that it's tempting to back to regular MVC :)