# asp..net hot reload with library project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, hot-reload

Is it possible to setup a ASP.NET Core MVC Blazor project to hot reload another project containing a component library? I think I saw it working once or twice but in the majority of cases it does not seem to work out of the box. Can I control it?
Tried  without success.
Any hints?

Comment: [Could your kindly check the libray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60868054/7687666), it should be the best choice.

Comment: Thank you Jason you sent me in the right direction ...
I added this to my project ...


'<ItemGroup>
  <Watch Include="..\..\Shared\UI\Web\TheComponentsComponents\*.csproj" />
  <Watch Include="..\..\Shared\UI\Web\TheComponentsComponents\**\*.razor" />
  <Watch Include="..\..\Shared\UI\Web\TheComponentsComponents\**\*.cs" />
  <Watch Remove="..\..\Shared\UI\Web\TheComponentsComponents\bin\**" />
  <Watch Remove="..\..\Shared\UI\Web\TheComponentsComponents\obj\**" />
</ItemGroup>'

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I think it's the solution for your post. Could you summarzie it as answer below, it might help other forum users.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for it. I added those watch statements to my `.csproj` file.
Be aware of the Remove statements. Otherwise it could watch files from another project.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Watch Include="..\..\Shared\UI\Web\TheComponentsComponents\*.csproj" /> 
    <Watch Include="..\..\Shared\UI\Web\TheComponentsComponents\**.razor" />
    <Watch Include="..\..\Shared\UI\Web\TheComponentsComponents\***.cs" />
    <Watch Remove="..\..\Shared\UI\Web\TheComponentsComponents\bin*" /> 
    <Watch Remove="..\..\Shared\UI\Web\TheComponentsComponents\obj**" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```